# How to find how many messages have gone to the DLQ for the past year in Azure Servicebus queue?

Tags: azure, queue, servicebus, dlq

We have a query that archives all of the DLQ messages in our service bus queue after a set period of time. The problem is that these messages are archived in bulk so we don't have a specific number. Is there a way to find the total number of messages that has gone to the dlq for the past 6 months or a year?

Comment: where are they archived to?

Comment: They're archived to a blob. But they're archived at certain intervals so if there are 5 messages they'll be archived as 1 file and so we have many such files with random numbers of such messages @codebrane

Comment: can you archive them to a blob container that only contains those files, then download them and process them offline, e.g. scripting with ruby or something?

Comment: or archive them yourself with a logic app or a function with a TimerTrigger? It's easy to retrieve all messages (i.e. remove, rather than peek) from the DLQ, parse them and archive them in whatever format you need with whatever filename you need.